# Can't get usb bluetooth adapter to work

Tags: 14.04, usb, bluetooth

I've been trying to use an usb bluetooth adapter, but all the instructions I found on the internet have not worked.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

A brief description of the problem:
- `lsusb` does not list the dongle, even though it is connected.
- `hciconfig -a` produces **no output whatsoever**.
- `rfkill list` **also** lists nothing.

I've tried reinstalling the bluetooth related packages, by running
`sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3`
(bluez-dbg is probably overkill, though)
and I've tried adding `rfkill unblock bluetooth` to the **/etc/rc.local** file.
None of these have worked.
Any suggestions?

**edit:**

After trying to use it on another computer, running Windows, the system was seemingly unable to properly use the device.  It seems like the device itself is broken. Thanks for the help.

Comment: does 'dmesg' show anything when you plug and unplug the device?  If so, paste here it does.  If it doesn't, well, that's a problem.

Comment: If an USB device was not recognized on `lsusb` adding drivers or changig bluetooth settings will not help. Did you try with another USB port? Is the device working on another machine?

Comment: `dmesg`'s output is as follows:  
[12549.868016] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using uhci_hcd  
[12549.992019] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71  
[12550.220022] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71  
[12550.436016] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using uhci_hcd  
[12550.560021] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71  
[12550.788015] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71  
[12551.004018] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using uhci_hcd  
[12551.420057] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 12, error -71  
[12551.532...